# Cannot Instantiate InitialContext

Tags: glassfish, jms

I have a class that acts as standalone client for Glassfish V3 JMS queue. This class works fine from my localhost, i.e. both glassfish server and the standalone client are on my local PC.

Now I need to install this client on a Linux machine. Glassfish V3 is already running on this Linux machine. I have added `appserv-rt.jar` from the glassfish installation directory and added it in the directory of standlaone client and set the classpath. But I keep getting this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
        at com.cisco.zbl.controller.ZblBulkUploadThread.run(ZblBulkUploadThread.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is my Java code:

```
  public class ZblBulkUploadThread implements Runnable,MessageListener{

    private static final Category log = Category.getInstance(ZblBulkUploadThread.class) ;


            private Queue queue;

    public void run()
    {
            try
            {
                    ZblConfig zblConfig = new ZblConfig() ;


                    InitialContext jndiContext = null;

                    MessageConsumer messageConsumer=null;

                    Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",  "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",  "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");

                    jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);

                    log.debug(zblConfig.getProperty("JMSConnectionFactoryName")) ;

                    //System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

                    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(zblConfig.getProperty("JMSConnectionFactoryName"));


                    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();


                    Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                    queue = (Queue)jndiContext.lookup(zblConfig.getProperty("JMSQueueName")) ;

                    messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

                    connection.start();

                    while(true)
                    {

                            Message message = messageConsumer.receive() ;


                            ObjectMessage om = ((ObjectMessage)message) ;
                            try
                            {

                                    RedirectFile file = (RedirectFile)om.getObject() ;

                                    log.debug("filePath "+file.getFilePath()) ;
                                    log.debug(" userName "+file.getUserName()) ;
                                    log.debug(" mode is "+file.getMode()) ;

                                    processMessage(file,zblConfig) ;

                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                    log.error("ERROR "+ex.getMessage()) ;
                                    ex.printStackTrace() ;
                            }
                    }


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                    ex.printStackTrace() ;
                    log.error("Error "+ex.getMessage()) ;
            }
    }
```

The error comes at this line: `jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);`

It does not make any difference if I use the no-arg constructor of `InitialContext`.

Here is my unix shell script that invokes this java program (Standlaone client):

```
  APP_HOME=/local/scripts/apps/bulkUpload;

CLASSPATH=.:$APP_HOME/lib/gf-client.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/zbl.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/log4j-   1.2.4.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/javaee.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-examples-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-excelant-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/appserv-rt.jar:


 echo "CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH";

 export APP_HOME;
 export CLASSPATH;

 cd $APP_HOME;

 #javac -d . ZblBulkUploadThread.java

 java -cp $CLASSPATH -Dzbl.properties=zbl-stage.properties    -Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory com.cisco.zbl.controller.ZblBulkUploadThread
```

Please help me - I have been stuck on this problem for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

do a `which java`  command and see if jdk is being picked up correctly. I doubt that linux is picking gc4j

update:

change this line 
`CLASSPATH=.:$APP_HOME/lib/gf-client.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/zbl.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/log4j-   1.2.4.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/javaee.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-examples-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-excelant-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/appserv-rt.jar:`   to

```
CLASSPATH=.:$APP_HOME/lib/gf-client.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/zbl.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/log4j-   1.2.4.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/javaee.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-examples-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-excelant-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta5-20111217:$APP_HOME/lib/appserv-rt.jar
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding naive - but what is gc4j?

Comment: Java version shows "1.6.0_24".I am able to compile Java programs on that machine.Even this standalone client code - I could compile on this Linux machine.Should I ask System admin to look at gc4j configuration?

Comment: Yes I did.It just outputs /usr/bin/java .Then I tried java -version to get the version.

Comment: I edited my answer take a look at it , try the command that I wrote and let me know

Comment: I tried that(removed : from the end) but still the same error.

Comment: I am thinking there may be some issues with the way appserv-rt.jar is being read by JDK.Upon opening this ,I see there is no class files.There is just a META-INF folder - the whole structire is like this :- appserv-rt.jar\META-INF\maven\org.glassfish.extras\appserv-rt\ .Same file works fine on my local machine(windows os).But when I copy it to linux,it is as if that jar file does not exist at all.

Comment: try putting appserv-rt.jar at the start of CLASSPATH and see

Comment: I solved this by referencing to appserv-rt.jar in Glassfish directory on same host rather than copying that jar file to client directory and putting that classpath.Thanks Satya for looking into it.